# How to get eks worker node ip displayed in terraform output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I have a terraform script where the eks cluster and node groups are created by terraform and then kubernetes pods are deployed onto it. I want the worker node ip created by terraform to be displayed as part of terraform output.

How can I achieve this?
I want to define in outputs.tf file file as such:

```
output "Worker-node-ip" {
  description = "This is the private ip of worker node"
  value = aws_eks_node_group.example. ???
}
```

But I dont know what attribute value to provide for terraform to get the ip address.

Edit: I am using the standard terraform code available in terraform docs for creating EKS worker nodes.

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "example" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.example.name
  node_group_name = "example"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.example.arn
  subnet_ids      = aws_subnet.example[*].id

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 1
    max_size     = 1
    min_size     = 1
  }

  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 2
  }
launch_template {
    name    = aws_launch_template.Example_eks_launch_template.name
    version = aws_launch_template.Example_eks_launch_template.latest_version
  }

  # Ensure that IAM Role permissions are created before and deleted after EKS Node Group handling.
  # Otherwise, EKS will not be able to properly delete EC2 Instances and Elastic Network Interfaces.
  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.example-AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.example-AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.example-AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
  ]
}

### Defining Launch template for worker node creation ###
resource "aws_launch_template" "Example_eks_launch_template" {
  name                   = "Example_eks_launch_template"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.Example.id, aws_eks_cluster.example.vpc_config[0].cluster_security_group_id]
  image_id               = "ami-0d5cbb67678bc879c"
  user_data = base64encode(<<-EOF
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="
 --==MYBOUNDARY==
 Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
 #!/bin/bash
 /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh example
 --==MYBOUNDARY==--\
  EOF
  )

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"

    tags = {
      Name = "EKS-MANAGED-NODE"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using to the question.

Comment: Added the code for worker node creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `tag_specifications` to get the info:

```
data "aws_instances" "my_worker_nodes" {
  instance_tags = {
    Name = "EKS-MANAGED-NODE"
  }
  instance_state_names = ["running"]
  depends_on = [aws_eks_node_group.example]
}

output "my_worker_nodes" {
  value = { for i in range(length(data.aws_instances.fcs.ids)) : data.aws_instances.fcs.ids[i] => data.aws_instances.fcs.private_ips[i] }
}
```

Example a node group with 3 worker nodes will output a map that looks like this:

```
my_worker_nodes = {
  i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx = "a.b.c.d"
  i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx = "a.b.c.d"
  i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx = "a.b.c.d"
}
```

Comment: This helped me with my requirement. Thanks a lot!.. Just one thing, it appends a tolist in the output , how can I remove it?                                                                        
  ```                                                                                                                  
  my_worker_nodes = {
  "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" = tolist([
    "<ip-address>",
  ])
}
```

Comment: Can you check if your code is the same as the answered; the code output a map, no list is involved.

Comment: Yes, my code was different I copied as is and now its working fine. Thanks a lot for your help.